# Power rule for the limits of convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

The "Power Rule" for null sequences states that

> If a null sequence of non-negative terms is raised to a positive
>   power, the resulting sequence is also a null sequence.

Ok, can this rule be generalised to the following?

> If a sequence of non-negative terms that converges to the limit $l$ is
>   raised to a positive power $p$, the resulting sequence converges to
>   the limit $l^p$.

Comment: The function $f(x)=x^p$ is continuous, so ...

Comment: If $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to x$, and $f$ is continuous, what can you say about $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$?

Comment: Hang on, and I'll write up an answer.

Comment: The motivation for my question is that my textbook gives the following Combination Rules for the limits of convergent sequences: sum, multiple, product, quotient, reciprocal rule. And I was wondering why the power rule for null sequences is not also extended here. And I see from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/83460/21813 that the power rule does apply for the limits of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Proposition:** Suppose that $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is continuous. Let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence in $[0,\infty)$ converging to $a$. Then $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to f(a)$.
>
> **Proof:** Let $\epsilon>0$; since $f$ is continuous, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$. Since $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to a$, there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n-a|<\delta$ whenever $n\ge n_0$. But then $|f(x_n)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge n_0$, so $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to f(a)$. $\dashv$

This result actually holds in much greater generality: if $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, and $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to a$ in $X$, then $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to f(a)$ in $Y$; the proof is identical if $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces and very similar even for general topological spaces. In words, *continuous functions preserve convergent sequences*.

Now just observe that if $p>0$, the function $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty):x\mapsto x^p$ is continuous, and your generalization follows immediately.

Comment: What a useful theorem! Thank you.