# How to prove that if $\lim a_n = L$ then $\lim a_n^r = L^r$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

I am trying to prove that:

> Given that the sequence: $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ has a limit $L$ (where $\forall n \in \mathbb N, a_n>0$), the sequence $(a_n^r)_{n=1}^\infty$ (where $r>0$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$) has a limit $L^r$.

I can prove in for instance for $r=\frac{1}{2}$:

> Given $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$, one can show that $\forall \epsilon >0$,  $$|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{L}|=\left|\frac{(\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{L})(\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L})}{(\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L})}\right|=\left|\frac{a_n-L}{(\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L})}\right|<\epsilon.$$

But, I don't know how to make it general.
Is it true that $a_n^r-L^r \leq (a_n-L)^r$,
for $a_n$, $L$ and $r$ that satisfy the above requirements?

**edit**: I have encountered the question in a course in which functions and continuity are thought after sequences, so my intention in the question was to use only sequences (and of course, completeness of reals, the property of Archimedes, real numbers axioms, definition of sequences limits, arithmetic  sequences limits etc..)

Comment: You may use the continuity of$e^x$ function....

Comment: Essentially this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83460 ?

Answer (score 1):

We know that a sequence is a function whose domain is natural numbers.Let f be that function, now apply [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83460/proof-of-power-rule-for-limits).

Comment: The meaning is to prove it without using theory of continuous functions.. I encountered this question in a course where functions limits is thought after sequences limits..