# Limit question calculus

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone help me understand how this limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}((n+1)/n)^n$ becomes $(1)^\infty$ (undefined)?  I understand the limit can be found with logs but I'm still stuck on how this part is undefined.

limit in question:

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n} = 1^{\infty}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: When $n\to\infty$, the base $\frac{n+1}n \to 1$ and the power $n \to \infty$. Hence the _indeterminate_ form $1^\infty$ (may or may not be undefined).

Comment: Take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nop746tkRsc and also look at this property: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83460/proof-of-power-rule-for-limits (they explain what @peterwhy said)

Comment: @CésarVB video very helpful ty.

Comment: Also, I think your question is answered in this post: Why is $1^∞$ considered to be an indeterminate form?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form

Comment: first when we say $1^ \infty $ what do you think $1$ means and what do you think $\infty$ means because from the question it seems you think that $1$ is not a limit to $1$ for example $\frac{n}{n+1} \to 1$ but it is not $1$ for any $n$ secondly what does  $\infty$ means for you ? is it "real" infinity because $\infty$ is not a number so  $1^ \infty $ is meaning-less
>

what we meant by $1^ \infty$ being indeterminate that if some $a_n \to 1$ and $b_n \to \infty $ the we can't say any thing about $a_n ^{b_n}$ i.e it can be any value

Comment: example 1 ${a_n =1} , b_n = n$  then $a_n ^{b_n} \to 1$
example 2 ${a_n =\frac{n}{n+1}} , b_n = n *c$  for some constant $c$ then $a_n ^{b_n} \to e^{-c} $ which can be any thing  depending on $c$

Answer (score 1):

$ 1^\infty =1$ Where $1$ is exactly $1$.

But the all the problem happens when $1$ is little bit greater or less than exact $1$ (In formal language $\to 1$) , then $1^\infty$ is indeterminate form which means by the nature of infinty you can get any limit for $1^{\infty}$.

for instance, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n} = \frac{1}{e}$ ( Which is also in $1^\infty$ form)

You can verify the facts numerically by taking $n=10^{10}$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your confusion correctly, The confusion lies in $1^{\infty}$ part, When we say $1^n=1$ Which is of form $a^n$ for all Real values of "$n$" ,We absolutely know $a=1$ exactly

While talking About limits

When We say $(\rightarrow1)^{\rightarrow \infty}$

Now consider

$(\rightarrow1^{+})^{\rightarrow \infty}$

Let us see what binomial expansion tells us

$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{n}+\binom{n}{2}(\frac{1}{n})^2.....$

Now $\binom{n}{0}$ and $\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{n}$ are obvious determinate forms when $n\rightarrow\infty$,

All other sums like

$\binom{n}{2}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2!(n^2)}$ and $\binom{n}{3}\frac{1}{n^3}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!(n^3)}$ etc. should be evaluated individually by applying limits

which means all $(\rightarrow1^{+})^{\rightarrow \infty}$ cases are not same, because each will have different binomial or other expansions

A quick demonstration of individual application of limit for above series is as follows

$L=\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n(n-1)}{2!(n^2)}=\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2(1-\frac{1}{n})}{2!(n^2)}=\frac{1}{2!}$

similarly doing such evaluations

you will get that

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!}.........$

Now using expansion for $e^x$,Which can be proved without proving this limit, So that The argument is not circular and putting $x=1$ gives the same Summation obtained above

Hence the Limit $L=e$

Answer (score 0):

((n+1)/n)=(1+1/n), when this is raised to the power of n it approaches e, the base of the natural logaritms, as n approaches infinity.  This can be easily checked with a simple calculator, and it is very old knowledge.

Comment: Hi, the question is not about the value of the limit, but rather about why $1^{\infty}$ is "undefined".

Comment: Please note in OP's post, "I understand the limit can be found with logs but I'm still stuck on how this part is undefined."