# When is the power rule for limits acceptable to use?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Suppose you wish to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1+x^2)^{-a}}{e^{-bx}}$$

for real numbers $a,b>0$. My instinct here is to rewrite as
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+x^2}{e^{\frac{bx}{a}}}\right)^{-a}$$
and then take the limit inside the parentheses:
$$\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+x^2}{e^{\frac{bx}{a}}}\right)^{-a} \tag{$\ast$}$$
From here I would split the limit into two terms and use L’Hôpital’s rule on the second term to get the answer, $\infty$.

My question is whether the move I made in the starred equation is valid here, as I have only ever seen the power rule for limits stated for positive integer powers.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83460/proof-of-power-rule-for-limits) probably answers your question (basically the rule holds).

Comment: (Limits and L’Hôpital’s rule are calculus, so why do you have this question tagged "precalculus"?) Limits may be exchanged with a function *if the function is continuous* at the limit of the inner expression: if $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = b$ and $f(x)$ is continuous at $b$ (i.e., $\lim_{x \to b} f(x) = f(b)$, then $\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = f(b)$. Alternatively, if there is some open interval about $a$ on which $g(x) \ne b$ (except possibly at $x = a$), then $\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = \lim_{t \to b} f(t)$ even if $f$ is not continuous, or even not defined at $b$.

Comment: Since $x^r = e^{r\ln x}$ for $x > 0$ and any $r$, and $e^x, \ln x,$ and $rx$ are continuous functions of $x$, this justifies the exchange of limit and exponent.